# How to perform regression with a sensitivity analysis in R

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, sensitivity-analysis

Without using non-base packages like `plm`, how can I perform a fixed effects regression in R with a sensitivity analysis for one or several other variables?

Some example data is:

```
structure(c(1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 
1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 91.1, 92.3, 93.1, 94.2, 
95.4, 96.7, 98, 100, 102.3, 104.7, 108.5, 110.8, 114.5, 119.6, 
123, 126.1, 7.2332, 5.3403, 5.9663, 5.1235, 4, 3.6917, 4.3858, 
4.6468, 4.6379, 5.5128, 4.6821, 0.6423, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 6.7360515702062, 
4.96950459299037, 5.76444262988059, 6.39149538862192, 2.71199488290959, 
2.57064352206969, 5.51597248333863, 5.00144613999387, 4.94132213682417, 
4.70318166203843, 5.59648600984904, 1.51472926777175, 0.85868748021582, 
0.638279662987065, 1.75717939971928, 1.16959872821281), .Dim = c(16L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Time", "r1", "response", "explanatory"
)))
```

where `Time` are the years to examine the potential relationship between the explanatory variable, `explanatory` and the response variable `response`. `r1` is to be used in the sensitivity analysis.

Any considerations on how to perform the sensitivity analysis especially (with code) much appreciated since for the fixed effects without sensitivity analysis I believe I can just do:

`lm.model<-lm(response ~ explanatory + Time, data=df)`

Comment: Sensitivity analysis is a bit general, what in particular are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure but anything that would allow me to examine the effect on an explanatory variable~response variable relationship in the context of another potential input variable. The approach under "Regression analysis" [here](http:///en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis#Core_methodology) may be suitable

Comment: I think the reason you aren't getting answers is because it is still too broad.  What kind of exercises are you interested in performing?  The kind of sensitivity analysis you do depends to a pretty large extent on the problem you have at hand.

Comment: The question I want to ask is whether any relationship (let's assume there is one) between `response` and `explanatory` holds (or does not hold) if we account for `r1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use summary(lm.model) to learn quite a bit.

`summary(lm.model)`

```
Call:
lm(formula = response ~ explanatory + Time, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6329 -0.8349 -0.2382  0.4962  2.5250 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.889e+02  1.310e+02   6.023 4.28e-05 ***
explanatory  2.217e-05  5.469e-05   0.405    0.692    
Time        -4.122e-01  6.873e-02  -5.997 4.47e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.267 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7363,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6957 
F-statistic: 18.15 on 2 and 13 DF,  p-value: 0.0001726
```

The coefficient results are output below.  The p-value tells you the probability of observing this coefficient if the true value is actually 0.  This, for your case, is .692.  This is very probable then that there is no linear relationship between explanatory and response.  There is, however, very likely a statistically significant time trend.  It's magnitude though may or may not be economically meaningful.

Did you try plotting a scatterplot of (response,explanatory)?

```
plot(df$response,df$explanatory,col='red',pch=19,cex=2,main='Explanatory vs. Response')
```

> 

[image]

```
plot(df$response,df$time,col='red',pch=19,cex=2,main='Explanatory vs. Response')
plot(df$explanatory,df$time,col='red',pch=19,cex=2,main='Explanatory vs. Response')
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess the example data I gave is bad. Let's assume there is a relationship between `explanatory` and `response`, how can I test if `r1` confounds, modifies or mediates this relationship?

Comment: Plot all the variables vs each other.  Then do regressions with all the variables, then more where you exclude one or the other.  You will see that two of the variables are highly collinear.

Comment: Could you add this as a code example?

Comment: See the bottom.

Comment: But the regression? Sounds like what you're describing is something like regression with backwards elimination. Is that correct and is it still consistent with a fixed effects approach?

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_%28statistics%29